# JQuery post and name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form and want to post this, using jQuery. In Django I have some custom code which depends on the name attribute of the form (if request.POST.get('BoekForm2'))

Here is my page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('form').hide();
          $('img').click(function() {
          $('select option').eq(this.alt-1).prop('selected','true');
          $('input:last').prop('Boekform2','Volgende');
//        $('form').get(0).setAttribute('name', 'BoekForm2');
          $('form').submit();
})
})
</script>
<form action="" method="post">
<div style='display:none'>
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ee47602b5994f986b0e6bfa5b814096c' /></div>
<label for="id_Type_activiteit">Type activiteit:</label>
    <select name="Type_activiteit" id="id_Type_activiteit">
         <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
         <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="BoekForm2" value="Volgende" id="BoekForm2"/>
</form>

 <img  style="cursor:pointer" src="../image1.jpg" alt="1" />
 <img  style="cursor:pointer" src="../image2.jpg" alt="2" />
 <img  style="cursor:pointer" src="../image.jpg" alt="3" />
```

When I post this form manually the POST info looks like:

```
Type_activiteit     u'1'

csrfmiddlewaretoken     u'ee47602b5994f986b0e6bfa5b814096c'

BoekForm2           u'Volgende'

When I post this form using jQuery the POST info looks like:

Type_activiteit     u'1'

csrfmiddlewaretoken     u'ee47602b5994f986b0e6bfa5b814096c'
```

How do I get the name of the form in the POST info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very fast solution would be to add the form name inside the form using a hidden filed and on post get the hdn field value on the server

```
<form>
 <input type='hidden' name="formname" value="secondform"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. Just out of curiosity: Why does this work, and the name attribute of the input type submit doesn't? Is it because type is hidden?

Comment: no it is by design that input of type submit values are not sent in the form post